# Get the pageUrl (randompage.html) from a string using regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How can i extract the pageurl randompage.html from the following path using regex?

/stars/thisisapath/randompage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any path ending in `.html`, this should work:

```
[^\/]+\.html$
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/pauXBb/2

If you want it to be more generic, and accept any file extension, then try:

```
[^\/]+\.[^.]+$
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/pauXBb/3

Comment: The first one(ending in .html) is fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What if i want to extract everything BUT the randompage.html ?

Comment: This should do `.+\/`

Comment: I end up with stars/thisisapath/. Any way to exclude the last /  so i end up with stars/thisisapath ?

Comment: This should do it `.+(?=\/)`

Answer (score 1):

```
string your = "/stars/thisisapath/randompage.html";
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"/: (.+?).html").Groups[1].Value;
```

the `match` will have your value of `randompage`. Now to this you can add the html with something like:

```
match+="html"
```

Comment: Or.. in order for the group to include the .html, use `\/([^\/]+\.html)$`

Comment: This `@"/: (.+?).html"` regex will also match `"/stars/thisisapath/randompagehtml"` because the `.` is not escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `([\w-\.]+\.)\w+`. It will find even string like this /stars/thisisapath/**random.page-5.html**

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular Expression `([^/]*)$`